# Im having trouble with Month comparison in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare months from a form, which are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 to getMonth()

I have been trying to figure it out for a while, and tried parsing to Int and making sure the Int's
are the same, i.e. single digits, but to no effect.

```
function checkCard() {

    var cardYearError = document.getElementById("cardYearError");
    var monthError = document.getElementById("cardMonthError");

    var date = new Date();
    var month = parseInt(date.getMonth()+1);
    var cardMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardmonth"));
    var year = parseInt(date.getFullYear());
    var cardYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardyear"));

    if (year > cardYear) {
        cardYearError.innerHTML="Sorry your card has expired :1";
        cardYear.focus();
        cardYearError.style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
    cardYearError.innerHTML="";

    if ( year === cardYear && cardMonth < month) {
        monthError.innerHTML="Sorry your card has expired :2";
        cardMonth.focus();
        monthError.style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
    cardMonthError.innerHTML="";

    return;
}
```

The year comparison works fine, but the second if statement will not work for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: credit cards use 2 digits for years, getfullyear returns 4 digits

Comment: Have you done some debugging? I.e. put a breakpoint or printed the values of `month` and `cardMonth` to see if they contain what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check `year`, `cardYear`, `cardMonth` & `month` first !
for this you have to log all these variables.

and you did not get the value of these two given lines

`var cardMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardmonth").value));`

`var cardYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardyear").value));`

now you can try this code and let me if its work fine.

```
function checkCard() {

    var cardYearError = document.getElementById("cardYearError");
    var monthError = document.getElementById("cardMonthError");

    var date = new Date();
    var month = parseInt(date.getMonth()+1);
    var cardMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardmonth").value));
    var year = parseInt(date.getFullYear());
    var cardYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("cardyear").value));

    if (year > cardYear) {
        cardYearError.innerHTML="Sorry your card has expired :1";
        cardYear.focus();
        cardYearError.style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
    cardYearError.innerHTML="";
    console.log(`${year} === ${cardYear} && ${cardMonth} < ${month}`)
    if ( year === cardYear && cardMonth < month) {
        monthError.innerHTML="Sorry your card has expired :2";
        cardMonth.focus();
        monthError.style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
    cardMonthError.innerHTML="";

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the html  value properties. It was reading the value and not what was between the tags as I had thought.

I tried using this:

```
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    demo.innerHTML=month+" "+cardMonth+" "+year+" "+cardYear;
```

To print the values and troubleshooted as I don't have breakpoints in notepad++.

Thanks for giving me the idea.